# Split() throws SCRIPT5007 error only in IE10

Tags: internet-explorer, d3.js

I'm using d3.js to grab an object and then splitting the translate(x,y) attribute to work with it somewhere else. This code works fine in FF, Safari, Chrome, and Opera, but in IE10 it errors out with SCRIPT5007 cannot find property split of undefined. I'm not using regex, just a comma, and I've looked through the various problems with earlier implementations of split() in IE, but since earlier versions don't even work with SVG, I don't care.

```
inObject = d3.select("#someObjectWithTransform");
if (inObject.attr("transform")) {
    var curXYa = new String(inObject.attr("transform"));
    var curXYb = curXYa.split(",");
})
```

I know that there's a value for inObject and that it's not .empty() and, as I've said, this works fine in every other browser.

Comment: What's the reason for using `new String(...)`? Why not skip the `new` and just use `var curXYa = String(inObject.attr("transform"))`? I'm not sure if that's what causes the error, but I wouldn't be totally surprised. BTW, IE9 has SVG too.

Comment: I tried that because I thought IE10 was having a problem with it not being declared as a String. It gives the same error with just var curXYa = in object.attr("transform") though I haven't tried with removing New.